# JTable JComboBox and Getting Selected Value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I need to get the selected item from a `JComboBox` in a `JTable` cell (as well as other data but I want to simplify my question by focusing on a single cell/column). The combo box is displaying and working so all I need is to get the selected item.

I cannot find anything that tells me where to do that in my code. All the examples seem exceedingly complex for what I would think is a routine process. My `JDialog` that contains the table, has a save button in it. I **think** the docs are telling me that all changes to the table are saved in the table model.

Am I correct that I extract the changed data from the table model in the listener for my save button? If so, it is not clear how I know what cells were changed unless I am supposed to process every cell regardless. Can someone correct/clarify my reasoning?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) (of the current code).

Comment: How do I do that if I don't yet know what to code?

Comment: You seek similar questions and first try things out, experiment, see what you can come up with

Comment: What Andrew is getting at, is that you have a cell editor with a combo box as editing component, it's just that we don't know how you implemented this. The answer depends on that. Hence to be able to answer you, we'd need a [MCVE] to know what you're dealing with.

Comment: *"How do I do that if I don't yet know what to code?"* I repeat.. **(of the *current* code)**. From your words above, it seems you've coded a dialog, a table and a combo box for one of the columns of the table. Post an MCVE of that. Makes it much easier for others to see things like, how the table model works, whether the combo is actually changing the data ..

Comment: BTW - 1) Yes. 2) That'd be a common way to do it. It is possible to keep a record of what has changed and only serialize those differences, but that is more complicated. 3) I think that is correct reasoning. -- Those are minimalist answers to your questions. For anything more than that, I suggest you post the MCVE of current code. Then people can provide more specific answers. Also it would help to know how the data is to be serialized (e.g. database, local file..).

Comment: ***where is your source code?***

Comment: Thanks. That was the confirmation I was looking for so I can start my code. It was not obvious (to me) from any of the documentation or examples I found.

Comment: *"Thanks."* No worries. I don't think my comment would make a good answer as-is, and I could not be bothered expanding it to become one. You might write up an answer yourself, or delete the question. And to the down voters: I cannot see why you chose to down-vote. This question was perhaps seeming 'too broad' at a cursory glance, but nobody voted as such. Why the down votes?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: not a down-voter, but perhaps because an MCVE was requested and none was forth-coming.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's my worry. I poorly communicated that while I thought an MCVE might encourage better, more complete answers, it was not vital in order to answer the OP's basic queries. That seemed to boil down to "is my interpretation correct?". It unnerves me to hear people state "you **must** post an MCVE for every question". It's occasionally vital, other times helpful, still other times, a waste of space - just noise.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: agree. But even so, it would have been nice to see his concrete code if only to fully clarify the question. I know that I think better when I see this.

Comment: (1-) `How do I do that if I don't yet know what to code?" ` you said: `Am I correct that I extract the changed data from the table model in the listener for my save button?` - try it!!!. If it doesn't work as expected then you have a real question to ask and you have a simple `mcve` to post. Make an effort if you want people to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to track table changes.

```
public static class CellIndex {
    private final int row;
    private final int column;
    private final int type;

    private final static int ROW_ADDED=1;
    private final static int ROW_DELETED=2;
    private final static int CELL_UPDATED=3;

    public CellIndex( int row,int column,int type ){
        this.row=row;
        this.column=column;
        this.type=type;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return column;
    }   

}
```

Code to  track cell changes

```
    final ArrayList<CellIndex> changedCellIndex = new ArrayList<CellIndex>();
    table.getModel().addTableModelListener( new TableModelListener() {

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            int type = 0;
            switch(e.getType() ) {
                case TableModelEvent.DELETE:
                    type = CellIndex.ROW_DELETED;
                    break;

                case TableModelEvent.UPDATE:
                    type = CellIndex.CELL_UPDATED;
                    break;

                case TableModelEvent.INSERT:
                    type = CellIndex.ROW_ADDED;
                    break;
            }

            int end = e.getLastRow();
            int start = e.getFirstRow();

            if( end < 0 ) {
                end = start;
            }

            for( int i = start;i<= end;i++ ) {
                changedCellIndex.add( new CellIndex(i,e.getColumn(), type));
            }
        }
    });
```